# default bootstrap in asp.net mvc project, how does it work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with ASP.NET MVC default project.
I can see that it uses bootstrap. However, when I run the project I don't see something like:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

as I would expect.

Instead I see something like:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=LzveySGbzre5hK6VV4ZexwQl1hUNcljL4UffuTMZH8g1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

which is actually the minimized bootstrap.

why is that???

Also, I'm inspecting the input field in the default forms (register, login) and I can see that there is the css rule:

```
input, select, textarea {max-width: 280px;}
```

However, when I perform searches on all my solution I can not find anywhere which contain such rule: `max-width: 280px` (I can't even find the string "280px")

What is going on? where did this 280px appears from?

Comment: `~/Content/Site.css` has the css rule you mention.

Comment: Regarding how bootstrap is included in the project, see the `BundleConfig.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder. Asp.Net uses this to make various bundles of files which get sent to the client. This makes it faster to deliver.

Comment: in your layout you should see `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`.. this is a style bundle found in `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` the link you see is a combination of `boostrap.css` and `site.css`

Comment: MVC is using Bundles which is what is what is doing the first part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check APP_Start\BundleConfig and code .css and site.css for manking bootstrap working... if you are using VS2013, you can choose MVC project that already includes bootstrap libraries...

Regards!!!